# О трудоёмкости (1)

Tags: преподавание

В начале 20 века некоторые слова содержали букву "ять" (например, в слове "бес" писали "ять" вместо буквы "е").

**Вопрос:** Какое время требовалось в среднем русскому мальчику для того, чтобы запомнить все слова, которые следовало писать через "ять" [согласно руководству "Методика русскаго языка", которое сочинил проф. Н.К. Кульманъ]?

Comment: Предлагаю сделать этот вопрос исследованием. Уж слишком многогранный.

Comment: Что за дискриминация по половому признаку? А девочки Вас не интересуют, да?

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы Вы ответили на вопрос: "Какое время требовалось в среднем русской девочке для того, чтобы запомнить все слова, которые следовало писать через "ять"?"

Answer (score 2):

> Какое время требовалось в среднем русскому мальчику для того, чтобы запомнить все слова, которые следовало писать через "ять"

*В пределах гимназического курса*, как говорил Ипполит Матвеевич Воробьяниов.
:-)

Comment: Я понял "как говорил Ипполит Матвеевич Воробьяниов", по вашему мнению.

Answer (score 2):

Такое же, какое требовалось для запоминания стихотворения:

Бѣлый, блѣдный, бѣдный бѣсъ

Убѣжалъ голодный въ лѣсъ.

Лѣшимъ по лѣсу онъ бѣгалъ,

Рѣдькой съ хрѣномъ пообѣдалъ

И за горькiй тотъ обѣдъ

Далъ обѣтъ надѣлать бѣдъ.

Вѣдай, братъ, что клѣть и клѣтка,

Рѣшето, рѣшетка, сѣтка,

Вѣжа и желѣзо съ ять, --

Такъ и надобно писать.

Наши вѣки и рѣсницы

Защищаютъ глазъ зѣницы,

Вѣки жмуритъ цѣлый вѣкъ

Ночью каждый человѣкъ...

Вѣтеръ вѣтки поломалъ,

Нѣмецъ вѣники связалъ,

Свѣсилъ вѣрно при промѣнѣ,

За двѣ гривны продалъ въ Вѣнѣ.

Днѣпръ и Днѣстръ, какъ всѣмъ извѣстно,

Двѣ рѣки въ сосѣдствѣ тѣсномъ,

Дѣлитъ области ихъ Бугъ,

Рѣжетъ съ сѣвера на югъ.

Кто тамъ гнѣвно свирѣпѣетъ?

Крѣпко сѣтовать такъ смѣетъ?

Надо мирно споръ рѣшить

И другъ друга убѣдить...

Птичьи гнѣзда грѣхъ зорить,

Грѣхъ напрасно хлѣбъ сорить,

Надъ калѣкой грѣхъ смѣяться,

Надъ увѣчнымъ издѣваться...

(Цит. по: Проф. Н. К. Кульманъ, "Методика русскаго языка", Спб., изданiе Я. Башмакова и Кo, 1914 (3-е изд.), стр. 182.) : http://gn.org.ua/yat#sthash.wzh2yI6X.dpuf

Comment: гнѣзда? не может быть! Я не верю своим глазам. Там же **е** перешло в **ё**. Неужели такое возможно?

Comment: Возможно, в украинском-гнiздо, а о происхождении слова гнездо идёт спор, его иногда возводят к *sed-садиться, а чаще к *gneti-жечь.*gnoizdom- первоначально означало выжженное в лесу место для дома Диалектное гнездо-поселение из нескольких изб, однокоренные гнев, гнедой тоже через ять.

Comment: Dear Людмила.

Принял к сведению Ваш ответ.

Если Вы знаете, сколько времени требуется для запоминания указанного Вами стихотворения, тогда сообщите эти сведения.

Разумеется, Вы вправе ответить так: "Время, требуемое для запоминания  стихотворения про белого, бедного, бледного беса, равно времени, требуемому для запоминания поэмы "Евгений Онегин"."

Comment: Да, бегемотус часто путает *есть* и *ять*. Полное единодушие со стопкраном)))))))

Comment: В зависимости от степени развития памяти и интеллекта - каждому своё. Точно так же, как и остальные правила орфографии. Кто-то имеет врождённое чувство грамотности, орфографическую зоркость, ему требуется один раз прочитать правило - и он поймёт его суть с одного раза,а кто-то и по окончании школы пишет с ошибками. "Среднего "времени усвоения не бывает.

Comment: 1. Меня интересует среднее время запоминания. А Вы рассказали мне о "врождённом чувстве грамотности", "орфографической зоркости" и т. п.

2. Если "среднего" времени усвоения учебного материала "не бывает", тогда невозможно планировать обучение школьника, например, в мужской гимназии. Do you understand me?

Comment: Гнѣздо и звѣзда - два узаконенных исключения из правила "ять в ё не переходит". Впрочем, оно не было общепризнанным.   
Есть ещё созвучное непечатное, где в Ё переходит даже И. 
>Да, бегемотус часто путает есть и ять. Полное единодушие со стопкраном.  
 
Хамить изволите?  
  
>"Среднего "времени усвоения не бывает.  
  
Ну это излишне категорично. Бывает даже температура, средняя по госпиталю. 
Другое дело, что сама постановка абсурдна. Грот приводил множество спорных случаев, часто написание менялось со временем. Как и сейчас кстати.

Answer (score 0):

Такое же, какое время требуется средней российской девочке, чтобы выучить все словарные слова. Всю жизнь.

//-----------------------------------

Гнѣздо и звѣзда - два узаконенных исключения из правила "ять в ё не переходит".

Впрочем, оно не было общепризнанным. 
Есть ещё созвучное непечатное, где в Ё переходит даже И.

> Да, бегемотус часто путает есть и ять. Полное единодушие со стопкраном.

Хамить изволите?

> "Среднего "времени усвоения не бывает.

Ну это излишне категорично. Бывает даже температура, средняя по госпиталю. 
Другое дело, что сама постановка абсурдна. Грот приводил множество спорных случаев, часто написание менялось со временем. Как и сейчас кстати.
А ***все*** слова никто не заучивал. Заучивали морфы, в основном - корневые.

Comment: 1. Ответ не по существу. Написан неряшливо.

2. Понял, что "бывает даже температура, средняя по госпиталю".

Comment: У нас и зарплата "средняя по стране"-у кого-то 120 тыс., а у кого-о 3 тысячи, а вместе получается вполне приемлемая цифра. о которой большинству остаётся лишь мечтать. Это "среднее по..." - цифра ирреальная, не существующая в действительности.